# how do I access an object's deep atribute using a bracket notation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I want to do this:

```
market['global']['name']
```

Like this:

```
market['global.name'] //undefined
```

Why? Because it would allow to loop through an array with different 'routes' instead of having to create a ton of exceptions

Comment: JavaScript isn't the kind of language that would let programmers extend its syntax. Maybe you should instead ask about how to accomplish whatever your actual need is.

Comment: Do you intend to use this with Node.JS or in the browser? I know you've tagged node, but wanted to check before posting. My solution won't work with both.

Answer (score 1):

you coud use something like this for a getter

```
function get_prop(obj,chain){
  chain=chain.split('.');
  var nobj={};
  for(var i in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      nobj[i]=obj[i];
    }
  }
  for(var i=0; i<chain.length; i++){
    if (nobj.hasOwnProperty(chain[i]) {
      nobj=nobj[chain[i]];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  return nobj;
}
```

ill post a setter later. but should be something along this lines

Comment: If you're using `for…in` then you should also be checking if the object `hasOwnProperty`.

Comment: thats just a skeleton, not a full fledge method, just to provide an idea of what to do besides is a getter if the property doesn't exist it will throw an error or return null. the idea with this answers should be teach people to fish, not deliver the fished already cooked

Comment: this is perfect for getting, but how would you alter ?